# Why I am getting uid as undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I am calling uid for storage and it keep getting undefined whats wrong?

```
handleAdminSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const auth = firebase.auth();
    let promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.SubEmail, this.state.subPasswrd);
    promise.then(user=> {
    console.log(user.uid)
      let email = this.state.SubEmail
      let em = email.replace('.com', '')
      let db = firebase.database();

      db.ref("Admins").child(em)
        .set({ "Admin": this.state.SubEmail, "password": this.state.subPasswrd, "Name": this.state.adminName  })
        .then(e => {
          console.log("succes")
          this.FetchAdmins()
        });


    })
    promise.catch(e => {
      alert("admin not created , Try again")
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type you get passed to the `then` is an [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential). To get the actual user, you have to access the `user` property on that. So:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.SubEmail, this.state.subPasswrd);
    .then(credential => {
        console.log(credential.user.uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `uid` is available on the `auth` object:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
let promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.SubEmail, this.state.subPasswrd);
promise.then(() => {
    console.log(auth.uid)
    ...
```